# タイムスタンプから日付を抜き出す

Tags: python, python3

下記のコードを実行するとファイルの作成日時がDateTime型で取得できますが、
そこから日付だけ抜き出すにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

```
filectime = os.path.getctime(filepath)
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(filectime)
# createdate = ?
```

Comment: `date()` メソッドではどうでしょうか。`createdate = timestamp.date()`

Comment: 動作確認しました。無事抜き出すことができました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

@metropolis 氏のコメントにより、 `datetime.date` メソッドを使うことで解決したようです。

> datetime.date()
>   同じ年、月、日の date オブジェクトを返します。
>   https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date

Comment: この回答は次のメタ質問を参考にコミュニティWikiとして投稿します。 [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1812/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e6%b8%88%e3%81%bf%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e4%ba%8b%e5%be%8c%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86)